# Python OOP and defining methods is classes

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm learning Python OOP now and confused with somethings in the code below:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Team:
    def __init__(self, name, players=None):
        self.name = name
        if players is not None:
            self._players = list(players)
        else:
            self._players = []

    def add_player(self, obj):
        self._players.append(obj)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._players)

    def __str__(self):
        out = [f"Team: {self.name}", "Players:"]
        out.extend(str(player) for player in self)
        return "\n".join(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    players = [Player("Afrasiab"),
               Player("Babak"),
               Player("Garshasp"),
               Player("Jamshid"),
               Player("Keyumars"),
               Player("Katayoun"),
               Player("Roham"),
               Player("Tahmoores")]

    iran = Team("Iran", players)
    print(iran)

    # equivalent:
    print("Team:", iran.name)
    print("Players:")
    for player in iran:
        print(player)
```

I'm wondering:

Why there is an underscore before *players* in 12th line of the code?

```
self._players = list(players)
```

In a nutshell, could you please explain how this code works?

Comment: Please ask *one* question, not *four*.

Comment: [What is the meaning of a single and a double underscore before an object name?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1301346)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why there is an underscore before players in **init** of class Team

The `__init__` method in Python is what a *Constructor* is in most other OOP languages.
This is a method that is called whenever a object of a class is instantiated.
That means when you call Player("NameOfPlayer") that init method is called.

> Why we should check if players is not None

if you hand `None` as a players list `list(None)` causes a TypeError.

> Why we should put a list before players in list(players)

That is imho a little strange code, you should check here if the type is a list of Players or Player and otherwise throw an error.

In addition to @Lomtrur's comment the underscore at the self._players variable indicates that _players is a private variable.

Comment: Pretty sure the underscore question refers to `self._players = list(players)`.